# Partition choice for Linux install, booting from CD on Mac

Tags: linux, mac, boot, partitioning, compact-disc

I downloaded the Linux iso and burned it to a CD, but before I boot from it, I want to know how/if I choose which partition Linux gets installed to. I have Linux Ubuntu 10.10 and Mac 10.5.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the GUI installer will ask if you want to partition, which disk partition you want to install to, and where you want to install the bootloader. I can't remember if the CLI installer does all three, but it WILL definately ask which partition to install to.

Just to be safe, i recommend doublechecking the release notes, for errors, but it should work, and warn you before doing anything

Comment: Then which button is it to boot from CD again? `C`? and what's CLI? And the CD should have the `.iso` and nothing more, right?

Comment: CLI command line interface... AKA the minimal installer. The cd should not HAVE the iso - it needs to be what's in the ISO. If the contents of the cd is a single iso file, you did it wrong. I have no idea what the key to boot from cd on a mac, sorry. Entirely Win/Lin myself

Comment: It won't let me burn any of the contents to the CD. Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/maciso use disk utility and the instructions there.

Comment: @Journeyman okay I did that, and now the contents are on my disk, but it still won't boot from it.

Comment: any error messages or is it just ignoring it?

Comment: It just goes straight from the startup sound <keypress "C"> to the startup screen <facepalm of desperation>